# query syntax "insert into" with R

Tags: r

I want to add real value calculated earlier on a postgresql database

```
Imp1=5/4
req=paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature',Imp1)")
resultat=dbGetQuery(con,req)
```

error

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERREUR:  la colonne Â« imp1 Â» n'existe pas
LINE 1: ...m_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature',Imp1)
                                                                  ^
)
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create executeINSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature',Imp1)
```

Comment: Typically, people will build queries in R using either `paste` or `sprintf`.

Comment: yes I used "paste" the error is on the value of "Imp1"  how to add a real number on queries?

Comment: You "used" `paste`, but you didn't _use_ `paste`. Compare `paste("some text Imp")` and `paste("some text",Imp)`.

Comment: I was unable to find the right syntax I am new to R

Comment: req=paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temperature' ))",Imp1,sep="")

resultat=dbGetQuery(con,req)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think should give you what you're looking for:

```
Imp1 <- 32.1
req  <- paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) 
VALUES (1,'temperature',",Imp1, ")",sep="")
```

That will output:

> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES       (1,'temperature',32.1)"

`paste()` will take any variable and return it's value as a string, and you chain items together with commas.  You can end the statement with a `sep=` parameter.  To be the most literal  (which I like doing for queries) I just use `sep = ""` and type the whole thing literally.  So If I had multiple values I wanted to insert I would do something like this:

```
var1 <- round(rnorm(5))
var2 <- c("'temp'","'pressure'","'precip'","'volume'","'mass'")
for(i in 1:length(var1)){
req <- paste("INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES   
(1,",var2[i],",",var1[i],")",sep="")
# not run, but do to send your query 
# dbSendQuery(conn,req)
print(req)
}
```

That will send the following queries:

> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'temp',0.09)"
>
> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'pressure',0.04)"
>
> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'precip',-1.2)"
>
> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'volume',0.78)"
>
> [1] "INSERT INTO important (num_cluster,type,indicateur_imp) VALUES (1,'mass',1.15)"

Comment: Note that when you send strings to a query, they are stored in the vector with double and single quotes e.g. "'temp'" not "temp" (assuming you want to send a string.